# swift - Fetching OpenGraph meta tags from URL

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to fetch og (OpenGraph) tags from a URL and display in the app. I get the tags properly for most of the websites, but for some, I don't.

ex. [This URL](https://search.sohoapp.com/properties/sale/beach-road-south-beach-residences-189763-singapore-54890)

When I render it on the browser and inspect, it shows me the meta tags, but when I try to fetch the html via cURL, it returns a html content without any meta. But, when I share the URL in Slack or FB, it renders the preview with the OG tags.

How do I do it on iOS?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with the URL you shared is that the site requires Javascript to be enabled.

If you don't have Javascript enabled, you just get back a basic page saying that you need to have Javascript enabled to browse the site (hence, no Open Graph tags).

Your browser, Slack and Facebook execute Javascript but cURL does not. Neither will a URLSession in iOS.

In iOS, the only way you're going to be able to get access to the HTML for such a website is to use a WKWebView to render the page.

Then, when it's loaded, execute some Javascript using `evaluateJavascript(_:completionHandler:)` to get the OG tags.

That's the only workable solution for these cases using iOS libraries.

The iOS client for Facebook, LinkedIn etc do not do this on their iOS client. Their iOS client calls their backend, passing the URL for processing, and receives back the preview. Javascript is executed as part of this backend process.

There are public APIs around that will help you to do the same thing, such as:

https://opengraph.io

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But Facebook, LinkedIn and other mobile apps show the preview properly. You mean that they're all rendering the url in a WKWebView and fetching the tags from there?

Comment: No, those companies are not processing URLs on their iOS client. Facebook’s preview feature a backend process. Their app calls their backend, passing the URL for processing and then receives the preview back. They even have caching so that if the URL is shared again they won’t have to go and parse the site’s HTML again. WKWebView isn’t an ideal solution, but it’s the only one you’ll find workable using iOS frameworks (as per your question). There are public API’s that you can use from your iOS app to do this on the backend, like Facebook etc do. Check out: https://www.opengraph.io

Comment: I've updated my answer since the scope of the question has changed.